# Relation between Mean Squared Displacement and Velocity Autocorrelation Function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

I'm trying to understand the relation between the Mean Squared Displacement in a sample of moving atoms (for example) and the autocorrelation function of the velocity. So I read in "Understanding Molecular Simulations" by Frenkel and Smit(second edition, 2002, p.89) that
$$\left<x^2(t)\right>=\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^tdt'dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>\\=2\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^{t'}dt'dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>$$
The first line is ok, but how can I go to the second one? I tried to break the integral in $dt''$ obtaining:
$$\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^tdt'dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>=\int\limits_0^{t}dt'\left[\int\limits_0^{t'}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right> + \int\limits_{t'}^{t}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>\right]$$
The last line from the book can be expanded as:
$$\int\limits_0^{t}dt'\left[\int\limits_0^{t'}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right> + \int\limits_{0}^{t'}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>\right]$$
And by comparing this to what I obtained, we can write that the last integral in here and the last one in my expression must be equal:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{t'}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right> = \int\limits_{t'}^{t}dt''\left<v(t')v(t'')\right>$$
but the first doesn't depend on $t$, while the second does...

Comment: The first region of integration is a square shape (in $t'$-$t''$ space) of area $t^2$. The second region of integration is a right triangle of area $\frac{1}{2}t^2$. If you draw a picture you will see that the first integral is twice the second integral, as long as the integrand is at least symmetric in $t'$ and $t''$, since the area of the square shape is twice the area of the triangle shape.

Comment: Thank you @hft!

Answer (score 2):

@hft's comment is the answer.  This also comes up in time-dependent perturbation theory as one does in QFT, and Peskin-Schroeder has a nice diagram about it. The referenced Eq. 4.21 is
$$
\int_{t_0}^t dt_1\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt_2 \, H_I(t_1) H_I(t_2) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^t dt_1\int_{t_0}^t dt_2 \, T\{H_I(t_1) H_I(t_2)\},
$$
where $T$ is the time-ordering "operator," which doesn't matter in your case because $v$ is a c-number that commutes with itself at other times.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it's even clearer!